# Disable exception with Infinity and NaN

Tags: c, nan, infinity, math.h

I have a huge project (not built by me) that is allowed to have `Infinity` and `NaN` values. Although it's allowed, it is not desirable. I [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html) that these values are generated by these kind of operations:

```
1/0 = &infin;
log (0) = -&infin;
sqrt (-1) = NaN
```

and, beside this, when they're reached, a `FP Exception` should be thrown.

If my project allows having operations with `NaN` and `Infinity`, I thought that `SIGFPE` would be handled somewhere, but I searched in the entire project and could not find it.

Is there another way to disable this exception? My goal is to be able to detect the first occurrence of these kind of values.

EDIT:
I'm using Windows and I intend to enable the signal, but before I enable, I'd like to understand if it got disabled.

Comment: So what should be the result of division by zero?

Comment: *"Is there another way to disable this exception? My goal is to be able to detect the first occurrence of these kind of values."* Doesn't that mean you actually want to *enable* this exception?

Comment: @stark I don't want to change it, I just want to identify when it occurs.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah, it would be nice to enable it, but first I'd like to understand how this got disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: Do you want SIGFPE to be thrown, or not? I'm using GCC, and on my installation, it is **not** thrown, and I could not (yet) find a way to have it enabled.

Comment: What OS are you running on ?

Comment: Edited my question with these info.

Comment: windows provides default signal handling routines , if the project is not defining a signal handler then the signal is probably being handled by the default handler.

Comment: From the GCC documentation you mentioned: *When exceptions occur (when exceptions are raised, in the language of the standard), one of two things can happen. By default the exception is simply noted in the floating-point status word, and the program continues as if nothing had happened. The operation produces a default value, which depends on the exception [...]). Your program can check the status word to find out which exceptions happened.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not going to have the problems you are talking about. By default, no FP exception are raised. From the Windows [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/floating-point-exceptions):

> By default, the system has all FP exceptions turned off. Therefore,
>   computations result in NAN or INFINITY, rather than an exception.
>   Before you can trap floating-point (FP) exceptions using structured
>   exception handling, you must call the `_controlfp_s` C run-time library
>   function to turn on all possible FP exceptions. To trap only
>   particular exceptions, use only the flags that correspond to the
>   exceptions to be trapped. Note that any handler for FP errors should
>   call `_clearfp` as its first FP instruction. This function clears
>   floating-point exceptions.

The same is true also for GCC, where the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html) says:

> When exceptions occur (when exceptions are raised, in the language of
>   the standard), one of two things can happen. By default the exception
>   is simply noted in the floating-point status word, and the program
>   continues as if nothing had happened. The operation produces a default
>   value, which depends on the exception [...]). Your program can check
>   the status word to find out which exceptions happened.

To enable exceptions (that will stop the execution of your program) in your Windows environment, you may try something like

```
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    _clearfp();
    unsigned int current_word = 0;
    _controlfp_s(&current_word, ~_EM_ZERODIVIDE, _MCW_EM);
    double div = 0.;
    double f = 1. / div;
}
```

For non blocking solutions, try using `fenv.h` as explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) on cppreference.com.

Comment: Maybe I should use `feraiseexcept` to enable?

Comment: I do not understand whether you want the exceptions to be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Now I understand the context. I want to enable.

Comment: Note that VC for pure C supports SEH with `__try {...} __except(){...}` Your program will then not abort (however, it won't tell you where the exception occurred. For that, remove the SEH and run the program in the debugger).